# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.net.useSystemProxies" "write")

Tags: java, jnlp, javafx-2

When I'm trying to open my javafx application in jnlp format I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.net.useSystemProxies" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.jugc.view.JugCMain.<clinit>(JugCMain.java:37)
    ... 10 more
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of operation are you doing at JugCMain.java:37 ?

Accessing system properties from jnlp/applet are subject to security restrictions.
All unsigned jnlp/applets are being run in sandbox with limited rights to avoid harming client's workstation.

You may want to sign your application if you want to use system propeties, see http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/sign/signing.html

If you are using NetBeans 7.1 for your JavaFX project you can just go to
"Project Properties->Build->Deployment" and click option "Request unrestricted access"

Comment: Just i'm using the system proxy         static {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    }